# this code produce a runtime error even though it produces the expected output

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int a[n][n];
    for(int j=1; j<=n; j++)
    {
        a[1][j]=1;

    }

    for(int i=2; i<=n; i++)
    {
        a[i][1]=1;
        for(int j=2; j<=n; j++)
        {
            a[i][j]=a[i-1][j]+a[i][j-1];
        }
    }
    cout << a[n][n];
    return 0;
}
```

I dont understand why this code produces a run time error even though it is correct and when compiled it produces the right output

Comment: Undefined behavior, accessing arrays out of boundaries. Read a beginners book before asking here 1st please.

Comment: If it were correct, wouldn't it...you know... not produce the runtime error? Your VLA is not standard C++, and more obviously you don't stay in bounds of your array. There are other things, but they're more style related and don't affect compilation and running. There's just a weird attitude among *many* beginners that the mistake can't possibly lie with them, that it has to be the tools or the compiler. It's very backwards thinking. The faster you can check yourself in this regard, the better your learning experience will be.

Comment: `for(int j=1; j<=n; j++)` is a bug

Answer (score 3):

When you have an array with `N` elements in it, the first one is going to be at index `0`, the seconds at index `1`, ... and the last one at index `N - 1`.

In your loops you are checking if `j <= N`, where `j` and `N` would have the same value for the last iteration. Therefore you are trying to acces a variable out of boundaries. You should change your loop to look like this: `for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)` ... to get working results.